Regarding Kolmogorov complexity, I need to show the following theorem.
The original text is in Japanese but I used ChatGPT to translate it.

For any natural number c, there exists a natural number n such that K(n)>c.

For any consistent axiomatic system T capable of developing mathematics, there exists a natural number c such that K(n)>c cannot be proved in T for any natural number n.

There is no algorithm to determine whether a given natural number is random.


I am not sure if these theorems are basic knowledge in this topic because my lecturer did not do a great job at conveying this to me. If can, can you explain these to me in simple words.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Hints: Statement 1  can be strengthened. Given $c$, all but finitely many $n$ have $K(n)>c$. And "finitely many" can be made more precise; $2^c$ will do. For statement 2, consider, for a temporarily fixed $c$, the algorithm "Search for a proof in T of a statement of the form $K(n)>c$ with a specific numeral for $n$. If you find one, take the first one you found and output that $n$." How long is this program (in terms of $c$)? Can its length be les tha  $c$? And when $T$ proves $K(n)>c$, can you trust it; i.e., must $K(n)$ actually be greater than $c$?

Thank you for the hints.

Does the third one also can be done using the first two hints?

I haven't thought carefully about statement 3, but the first thing I'd try is a proof by contradiction. So assume there is an algorithm for deciding randomness, and use it as a subroutine in another algorithm that searches for a sufficiently large random number and outputs it. "Sufficiently large" will have to be arranged so that this second algorithm witnesses non-ranndomness of its output. (That arranging will be similar to part of the proof of statement 2.)
